# ¿como extraer caracteres o números de una cadena en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una cadena de la que necesito solo tomar el valor numérico, este valor puede variar en longitud, puede ser de un dígito de 2 o 3 dígitos, no encuentro la manera de sacar por ejemplo de esta cadena 'LT 82 MF REND. GASTOS  -  AG. SAN VICENTE' solo quiero obtener 82 
o en este caso solo quiero obtener el 6 
'LT 6 DC REND. GASTOS' solo quiero en numero nada mas, LT nunca cambia al inicio.

Answer (score 2):

Si sabes la posicion de inicio, solo tenes que buscar la posicion de fin, y ella es el siguiente espacio posterior a tu posicion de inicio.

Para ello, tenes la funcion [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) que te devuelve la posion de una cadena dentro de otra, y podes usar como inicio un 4, ya que sabes que ahi seguro hay un numero.

Despues, para saber que cadena devolver, podes usar la funcion [SUBSTRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). La misma recibe una cadena, y una posicion de inicio y la cantidad de caracteres a traer..

Entonces, podrias hacer algo asi:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(campo, 4, CHARINDEX(" ", campo, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparto código de una función con SQL Server 2008:

FUENTE: http://jesusmgcia.blogspot.com/2017/10/extraer-solo-numeros-de-un-campo-string.html

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(column_name) 
from table_name
```

Comment: Puedes añadir una explicación del código que está en tu respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

No puedo añadir un comentario, a la respuesta de gbianchi, pero si alguien encuentra esto y lo quiere en MYSQL, dejo como lo resolví yo:

Uso la función [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)  y cambio la función *CHARINDEX* por [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate).

***LOCATE*** te devuelve la posición donde encuentra el elemento que le digas; entonces para pasar al elemento ***SUBSTRING***,  la longitud de la cadena, tienes que `(restar lo que te devuelve LOCATE - la posición inicial del numero)`.

Entonces seria algo así:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(campo, 15, LOCATE(" ", campo, 15) - 15))
```

Para convertirlo a numero, basta con multiplicarlo por 1:

```
 SELECT (SUBSTRING(campo, 15, LOCATE(" ", campo, 15) - 15)) * 1)
```